# How gcc optimize sum from 1 to 100 into 5050

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

I compiled following c program with `gcc -O3 -S a.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    printf("%d", sum);
}
```

The generated assembly code is as follow:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 10, 15    sdk_version 10, 15, 4
    .globl  _main                   ## -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $5050, %esi             ## imm = 0x13BA
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    callq   _printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ## -- End function
    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:                                 ## @.str
    .asciz  "%d"

.subsections_via_symbols
```

As if GCC ran the code and notice that the loop times are determined and GCC replaced the
whole calculating with the result 5050.

`movl    $5050, %esi`

How does gcc do this kind of optimization?
What's the academic name of this kind of optimization?

Comment: It might be "constant folding" in a sophisticated way.

Comment: constant propagation?

Comment: Seems to be an optimization specifically targeted at sums of first and second powers of arithmetic progressions. For example `sum += 3*i*i + 2*i  + 1;` gets optimized, but adding a third power `i*i*i` runs the actual loop.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find the specific flag, but with no luck. I was able to reproduce your result with only `-O1` so what I did after that was manually adding all the flags that are enabled by `-O1`. But when I did, I could not reproduce the result.

And as can be read in the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

> Not all optimizations are controlled directly by a flag. Only optimizations that have a flag are listed in this section.

So I assume this is done by something that `-O1` adds that does not have a flag.

Here is what I tried:

```
$ gcc -fauto-inc-dec  -fbranch-count-reg  -fcombine-stack-adjustments \
-fcompare-elim  -fcprop-registers  -fdce  -fdefer-pop  -fdelayed-branch  -fdse  \
-fforward-propagate  -fguess-branch-probability  -fif-conversion \
-fif-conversion2  -finline-functions-called-once  -fipa-profile  \
-fipa-pure-const  -fipa-reference  -fipa-reference-addressable \
-fmerge-constants  -fmove-loop-invariants  -fomit-frame-pointer \
-freorder-blocks  -fshrink-wrap  -fshrink-wrap-separate  -fsplit-wide-types  \
-fssa-backprop  -fssa-phiopt  -ftree-bit-ccp  -ftree-ccp  -ftree-ch \
-ftree-coalesce-vars  -ftree-copy-prop  -ftree-dce  -ftree-dominator-opts \
-ftree-dse  -ftree-forwprop  -ftree-fre  -ftree-phiprop  -ftree-pta \
-ftree-scev-cprop  -ftree-sink  -ftree-slsr  -ftree-sra  -ftree-ter \
-funit-at-a-time -S k.c 
cc1: warning: this target machine does not have delayed branches
$ grep "5050" k.s
$ gcc -O1 -S k.c
$ grep "5050" k.s
    movl    $5050, %esi
$
```

Comment: Also, `-Og` does not optimize the calculation, but `-O1` with all the options turned off which `-Og` is documented to disable still does.

Answer (score 0):

From reference in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html,
loop unrolling (`-funroll-loops`) and forward propagation pass on RTL (`-fforward-propagate`) are enabled with optimization levels `-O`, `-O2`, `-O3`, `-Os`.

Could you try to add `-funroll-loops` and `-fforward-propagate` to confirm?

Comment: No, `-O1 -fno-unroll-loops -fno-forward-propagate` still [optimizes it](https://godbolt.org/z/ha4T5c), while `-funroll-loops -fforward-propagate` does not.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#optimization-options mentions that `-O1` is not equivalent to individual optimization flags`. See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#optimization-flags for flags are enabled by individual optimization levels.

Comment: Right, but point of the comment was that `-funroll-loops` and `-fforward-propagate` have no effect on this optimization. The optimization is done with `-O1` and is not done without `-O1` regardless of the flags you mentioned, so they are not relevant to OP's question.